# Activate the zabbix trigger at a certain time

Tags: zabbix

I want to make the zabbix trigger work strictly at a certain time.

I read in the zabbix documentation that the time() function can help with this.

```
{test.domain:web.test.fail[trigger].last()}=0 and time()>000000 and time()<060000
```

But when i save the trigger, I get an error:

```
Invalid parameter "/1/expression": incorrect trigger expression starting from " time()>000000 and time()<060000".
```

Zabbix 5.0.18
I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix triggers are evaluated each time a new values is received.

You can check an item at cetain times using Custom Intervals.

[image: zabbix custom intervals example]

See: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/item/custom_intervals